# OnSelectedIndexChanged method stopped running

Tags: asp.net, html, post

After six months with the application running without a single change the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method is not being run any more.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBL_Comentario" runat="server" Visible="False" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="RBL_Comentario_OSIC"
    AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="naoimprime"
>
    <asp:ListItem Value="homologar">Obfuscated</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="retornar">Obfuscated</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The visibility is later turned on and works as expected.

When I check one of the buttons the page is posted but the method is not run. I can see in Firebug the `__doPostBack` javascript function running with the correct `eventTarget` just before submitting:

[image]

But the RadioButton HTML element `ct100$MainContent$RBL_Comentario$0` is not among those posted:

[image]

I tried IE8, IE9 and Firefox 10. Any hints? What could prevent the html element from being posted? I was thinking about some change in the anti virus software but don't know how to debug that as I can't disable it.

Comment: are radiobutton disabled in form after page has been loaded and why visiblity is false for the radiobutton list.

Comment: Has there been any code change at all? Is your radio button a dynamic control?

Comment: @keyboardP No changes. That repository is dusty now. The radio button is not a dynamic control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it is permitted to the user to enter some HTML and in this case it was entered into an HTML text editor and contained some not yet discovered (it is very dirty) broken HTML that is messing with the page's HTML.

Once the text was HTML escaped with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` the method was executed. It is not the solution as the raw HTML is show to the user.